# Convert address to bytes8

Tags: solidity, bytes

I want to convert `address` to `bytes8`, but I only managed to convert `address` to `bytes` this way:

```
bytes memory shortAddress = new bytes(8);
for(uint i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  shortAddress[i] = byte(uint8(uint(newContractAddress) / (2**(8*(19 - i)))));
}
```

Now I search for a way to convert from `bytes` to `bytes8`, but I think it would be more efficient to go directly from `address` to `bytes8`. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Can i ask why you are trying to convert address to bytes8? Address holds 20 bytes of value, hence you will lose some bytes of your address if you do such a thing.

Comment: `bytes8 shortAddress = bytes8(newContractAddress);`!!!

Comment: @goodvibration That doesn't work because of the reason that i just said. That code works for bytes20 not bytes8.

Comment: @Masoudjt: The reason you mentioned does not bother the person asking this question. He/she even calls the variable explicitly `shortAddress`, which means that they are perfectly aware of that. Saying "that doesn't work" is simply wrong in this context. It works well, and returns a result containing only some of the information, which appears to be what this dude wants.

Comment: @goodvibration I'm testing your code but i get this error: (explicit type conversion not allowed from "address" to "bytes8") why?

Comment: Try with `pragma solidity 0.4.25;`. Solc 0.5.x is probably more restrictive, but I suppose that `bytes8 shortAddress = bytes8(bytes20(newContractAddress));` could work in that case.

Comment: @Masoudjt I explicitly want an only 8 bytes long version of the address like goodvibration states. My contract supplies other contracts. This shortAddress version is stored in a mapping(bytes8 => address), where address is the newContractAddress. The reason is that someone has to type in an address to get to the contract newContractAddress. The whole address would be too much to type in by hand. At all the master contract will not supply more than 10.000 contracts. So I should be fine with this (I check for collisions).

Comment: @goodvibration `bytes8 shortAddress = bytes8(bytes20(newContractAddress));` does the job. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I was reading the [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/050-breaking-changes.html?highlight=bytes8#example) of solidity and found this:

> "Conversions between bytesX and uintY of different size are now disallowed due to bytesX padding on the right and uintY padding on the left which may cause unexpected conversion results. The size must now be adjusted within the type before the conversion. For example, you can convert a bytes4 (4 bytes) to a uint64 (8 bytes) by first converting the bytes4 variable to bytes8 and then to uint64. You get the opposite padding when converting through uint32."

So i would try with this:

```
bytes8(uint64(uint160(address)))
```

Comment: Correct. 
Hex digits==2*bytes==uint/4. Ethereum address (40 digits after 0x) is convertible in bytes20 which is convertible in uint160 without losing data